# Ошибки SP2=1503 и SP2=0152 после установки oracle_client

Tags: windows, oracle

Был установлен oracle_client на машину Windows Server 2012 R2 Standart x64

В конце установки было сообщение - net.framework 2 или 3 не удалось установить.
После был установлен net.framework 4.7 Перезагружался около 30 мин (Скорее причина невнем)

В cmd команда `sqlplus/nolog` выходят ошибки `SP2=1503 и SP2=0152`

Сервер Oracle пингуется

Comment: *В конце установки было сообщение - net.framework 2 или 3 не удалось установить.* Точно вот прямо так - "2 или 3"? И установка 4.7 никак не отменяет необходимости установки 2 и 3 (или 3.5?), если приложение их требует...

Comment: 2 и 3 точно в сообщении было, а вот 3,5 не могу точно сказать

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно командную строку и bat файлы запускать от имени Администратора.

Comment: И писать правильно: sqlplus /n**o**log. А почему от  Администратора?

Comment: Поправил. От Администратора почему-то получилось запустить. Думал что-то более серьезное.

Comment: От Администратора вообще то запускать не принято. Вам по шапке надают.

Comment: По обычному клику не запускается выходят ошибки.

Comment: Надо не кликать, а запускать в консоли. Ошибки принято исправлять.

Comment: Т.е. сделать консольный команду запуска и прикрутить к батнику

Comment: Нет, открыть консоль и там запустить .bat.

Comment: Запускаю через консоль - start file.bat как нужно не срабатывает, получается нужно через user Administrator? Как запустить через Admin?